# Express Router param

Tags: mongodb, express

I have a few Student models saved to a mongodb instance that I'm trying to fetch by username. Here's the mongoose model I have defined for Student:

```
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local : {
    username : String,
    password : String,
  }
});
```

In my routes file I'm trying to write a `router.param` so that I can perform CRUD operations to /students/< username >. My code looks like this:

```
router.param('student', function(req, res, next, username) {
  var query = Student.findOne({ 'username' : username });

  query.exec(function(err, student) {
    if (err)
      return next(err);
    if (!student)
      return next(new Error("Can't find student."));

    req.student = student;
    return next();
  });
});
```

I'm able to successfully query my `/students` route to fetch all the student documents in the database, but my `router.param` code doesn't seem to work. Whenever I try to `curl localhost:8000/students/<username>`, it can't find the student even though the student is clearly in the database and returns the "Can't find student." error. I'm not sure what's wrong with my `router.param` code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you use router.param, every time you pass that parameter you'll perform this action. I don't know if that's what you want, but as far as I can see, you should be using something like:

```
 router.get('/students/:username', function(req, res) {
     Student.findOne({'username': req.params.username}, function (doc) {
```

This way, when you send the username to a specific route you'll find that user and show all the data you need.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried a couple things following your suggestion. Firstly, in my `router.param` code, I changed `var query = Student.findOne({ 'username' : username });` to `var query = Student.findOne({ 'username' : req.param.username })`, which causes my get route to successfully return the document, but then I realized that any username I gave as input to the get route returned the same document, so it didn't exactly fix it.

Comment: I also tried your actual suggestion, but for some reason my get request always returns `null` and I have no idea why.

Comment: In this case, if you were able to at least get the param and run the query, maybe you should add some logs to trace out the param value.

You may need to debug the data in your database as well. 

Without access is really hard to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

The router param function is trying to find a student that has a username property, but according the StudentSchema it doesn't have a username property, it's actually nested under local , change your query to:

`Student.findOne({ 'local.username' : username });`

Answer (score 0):

Param name should be same when you performing any action!

```
router.param('student', function(req, res, next, student) { <--- Should be student
  var query = Student.findOne({ 'username' : student });<--- Should be student

  query.exec(function(err, student) {
    if (err)
      return next(err);
    if (!student)
      return next(new Error("Can't find student."));

    req.student = student;
    return next();
  });
});
```